# Routing for subdomains in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am trying to figure out how to route subdomains to different pages in Nuxt3, and I figured to try the routing rules seems it seems like the easiest option, but doesn't seem to work.

What would be the best way to direct subdomains to specific pages?

For instance, I have this in my nuxt.config.ts:

```
  routeRules: {
        'subdomain1.domain.com': { redirect: 'page1' },
        'subdomain2.domain.com': { redirect: 'page2' },
  }
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything at all. Any suggestions welcome!